# echo date(d-m-Y) in highchart

Tags: php, codeigniter

Working on high-chart -> pie chart

when i am trying to echo date(d-m-Y) it will subtract instead of print dd-mm-yyyy

```
data: [
    <?php foreach($result as $value):?>
        {
            name: <?php $d= strtotime($value['created_at']); echo date('d-m-Y', $d);?>,
            y: <?php echo round($calc_quality = $value['goodcount']/($value['totalcount'] + 0.0001 )*100,2); ?>
        },
    <?php endforeach?>
]
```

I want it to be 13-11-2021.Any solution?

[pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXUXy.png)

Comment: If you view the page source, what is in the `name` fields.

Comment: Probably missing some quotes to make it a string

Comment: Try this : `data: [
    <?php foreach($result as $value):?>
        {
            name: "<?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value['created_at']));?>",
            y: "<?php echo round($calc_quality = $value['goodcount']/($value['totalcount'] + 0.0001 )*100,2); ?>"
        },
    <?php endforeach?>
]`

Comment: The `highcharts` tag was used wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding ' ' solved it :

`name: '<?php $d= strtotime($value['created_at']); echo date('d-m-Y', $d);?>',`